# pandasの時間引き算について、時間の表示の問題

Tags: python, pandas

データフレームdf_sumは以下となります。
time              flow
2021/08/01 00:30  1627248
2021/08/02 00:30  1629168
2021/08/03 00:30  1629521
2021/08/04 00:30  1629521
2021/08/05 00:30  1629521

df_e=df_sum
df_e.index= pd.to_datetime(df_e.index)
df_e.index = df_e.index - timedelta(minutes=30)

以下を生成しました：
time        flow
2021-08-01  1627248
2021-08-02  1629168
2021-08-03  1629521
2021-08-04  1629521
2021-08-05  1629521

時間のフォーマットは2021/08/01 0:00にしたい場合、
どう修正したらいいですか？教えていただけると幸いです。

Comment: 最終的な結果として、どのような場面・対象で希望するフォーマットになって欲しいか、の情報を追加した方が良いでしょう。metropolisさんの方法はコンソール等のCUIで表示する際には必要ですが、文字列に変換してしまうため、変換後のデータを更に時間に関する処理を続けたい場合には元のdatetime関連オブジェクトに戻す必要があるかもしれません。oririさんの方法はJupyter Lab/Notebookやエディタ/IDEのプレビュー機能等のGUIを必要としたり、いったんファイルに出力してそれをブラウザで見る等の手順を踏む必要があるかもしれません。そうではなくてCSVのテキストファイルに出力する際に希望するフォーマットになっていれば良いのなら、[pandas.DataFrame.to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)の`date_format`パラメータで指定出来ると思われます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

※ `df_e.index` は `Timestamp` 型ではなく、`str` 型になります

```py
df_e = df_sum.copy()
df_e.index = pd.to_datetime(df_e.index)
df_e.index = df_e.index - timedelta(minutes=30)

print(type(df_e.index[0]))
df_e.index = df_e.index.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %-H:%M')
print(df_e)
print(type(df_e.index[0]))

# <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
#
#                     flow
# time                     
# 2021/08/01 0:00  1627248
# 2021/08/02 0:00  1629168
# 2021/08/03 0:00  1629521
# 2021/08/04 0:00  1629521
# 2021/08/05 0:00  1629521
#
# <class 'str'>
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。少し細かい質問ですが、もしこのような日付のフォーマット（日付の0を外す）でしたら、どうすればいいですか？

2021/8/1  0:00
2021/8/2  0:00
2021/8/3  0:00
2021/8/4  0:00

Comment: その場合も時刻と同様に `-` を付けます。`df_e.index = df_e.index.strftime('%Y/%-m/%-d %-H:%M')`

Comment: あれ？df_e.index.strftime('%Y/%-m/%-d %-H:%M')を実行してみましたが、2021-08-01 00:00:00こうになりました。

Comment: そうなりますと、そちらでは Windows 上で Pandas をお使いなのだと思います。その場合は `-` の代わりに `#` を試してみてください。`df_e.index = df_e.index.strftime('%Y/%#m/%#d %#H:%M')`

Comment: なるほど！windowsでpandasを操作したら、あなたと生成物が違う？初耳です。（インタフェースの関係かな...）もう希望の通りに生成した。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

`style` (styler) を使う方法

pandasの普通の表示形式とは異なる形式での表示
(データフレーム, インデックスなど内容は変化しない)

参考: [Table Visualization](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/style.html)

```py
df_e.style
#                       flow
# time
# 2021-08-01 00:00:00   1627248
# 2021-08-02 00:00:00   1629168
# 2021-08-03 00:00:00   1629521
# 2021-08-04 00:00:00   1629521
# 2021-08-05 00:00:00   1629521
```

詳細な書式を指定するには, `format()` / `format_index()` を使用

```py
df_e.style.format_index(lambda dt: dt.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M'))

#                   flow
# time
# 2021/08/01 00:00  1627248
# 2021/08/02 00:00  1629168
# 2021/08/03 00:00  1629521
# 2021/08/04 00:00  1629521
# 2021/08/05 00:00  1629521
```

ただし, `0:00` のような時刻表示には `strftime` が対応していないようなので, 独自の書式指定が必要かもしれません
(通常は, 0埋めした10進数で表記した時 (12 or 24時間表記) が利用される)

---

**追記**

`0:00` のような(0埋めではない)時刻表示はプラットフォーム依存のようだけど可能な模様

```py
# '%-H' のように '-' を途中に指定(UNIX系の場合)
df_e.style.format_index(lambda dt: dt.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %-H:%M'))

# 2021/08/01 0:00   1627248
```

> This only works on Unix (Linux, OS X), not Windows (including Cygwin). On Windows, you would use `#`, e.g. `%Y/%#m/%#d`.

参考: [Python strftime - date without leading 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904928/)